# ReportViewer - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

Having hard time getting ReportViewer control to run reports that have optional (NULL) parameters.

Reports are running fine directly on SSRS within browser, but when I try to run them inside ASP NET WebForm app I am getting null reference errors if optional parameter is set to null (null checkbox is cheeked).

I am getting this (misleading) StackTrace message: at icrosoft.ReportingServices.Common.DateTimeUtil.ParseDateToDefaultFormat => seems that this is some date parsing issue but parameters was integers, strings (no date time parsing is required).

I am using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0 with SSRS 2017 and sample app is built using this official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading to 150.1427.0 version of nuget package. It appears when I pass int or datetime values as parameters

*Exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DateTimeUtil.ParseDateToDefaultFormat(String strDateTime, CultureInfo formatProvider)

at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)*

According to the release notes they "Fixed a datetime parsing issue affecting certain locales."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/release-notes-ssrs-application-integration?view=sql-server-ver15

So I downgraded to version 150.1404.0 and the issue has gone

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to version 150.1449.0 (or higher), then that resolves the bug that produced this error.